# how to exclude directories from a phing copy task

Tags: task, phing

i have installed **Phing 2.4.7.1** on **Windows 7** and use the cygwin bash shell

I created a Phing task to copy files to a local directory and compress files, but I try to exclude certain directories without success. copy entire directory

the task is as follows:

```
<copy todir="${builddir}" includeemptydirs="true" >
    <fileset dir="." defaultexcludes="true">                
         <exclude name="cache/*" />
         <exclude name="build.*" />
         <exclude name="log/*" />
         <exclude name=".git" />
         <exclude name="/data/*" />
         <exclude name="/nbproject" />
         <exclude name="*~" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use two `*` for the subfiles:

```
<exclude name="cache/**"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't know if it is not just tag for human reading but something like this worked for me:

```
<fileset dir=".">                           
    <patternset>
        <include name="**/*.*" />
        <exclude name="dist/**" />
    </patternset>
</fileset>
```